# How to make content (videos and images) display properly? HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a pretty basic webpage with this menu that I found doing a tutorial online. It's a page of two videos and two images displayed in a horizontal column, with hopefully more images in the future. The page title and video look fine before I add the two images below them. After I add the images the video and title get cut off and I can't scroll upwards. I think it has to do with my wrapper id in CSS. If anyone could guide me in the correct direction on how to make my content display properly it'd be massively appreciated.

I've copy and pasted my code below.

```css
@charset "utf-8";
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

body {
  height: auto;
}

.wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(-200deg, #FEDD00, #FF6C2F);
  /* background: linear-gradient(375deg, #1cc7d0, #2ede98); */
  /* clip-path: circle(25px at calc(0% + 45px) 45px); */
  clip-path: circle(25px at calc(100% - 45px) 45px);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  overflow: auto;
}

#active:checked~.wrapper {
  clip-path: circle(75%);
}

.menu-btn {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  right: 20px;
  /* left: 20px; */
  top: 20px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: linear-gradient(-200deg, #FEDD00, #FF6C2F);
  /* background: linear-gradient(375deg, #1cc7d0, #2ede98); */
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

#active:checked~.menu-btn {
  background: #fff;
  color: #FF6C2F;
}

#active:checked~.menu-btn i:before {
  content: "\f00d";
}

.wrapper ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}

.wrapper ul li {
  margin: 15px 0;
}

.wrapper ul li a {
  color: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding: 5px 30px;
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 50px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.wrapper ul li a:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  background: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  left: 0;
  border-radius: 50px;
  transform: scaleY(0);
  z-index: -1;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease;
}

.wrapper ul li a:hover:after {
  transform: scaleY(1);
}

.wrapper ul li a:hover {
  color: #FF6C2F;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: -1;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  color: #202020;
  height: auto;
}

.content .title {
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.content p {
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.container {
  clear: both;
  overflow: auto;
}

.content img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.outer-container {
  width: 100%
}

.video-container {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  padding-top: 35px;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.video-container iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <input type="checkbox" id="active">
    <label for="active" class="menu-btn"></label>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="3d.html">3D</a></li>
        <li><a href="2d.html">2D</a></li>
        <li><a href="Animation.html">Animation</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Resume</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="title">Animation </div>
      <br> <br><br>
      <p>Get out of bed animation </p> <br>
      <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/91k2HK40Fis" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe><br>
      <br
        <br><br>
        <p>"Say Cheese" animation</p> <br>
        <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/IL2z54metGg" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe><br>

        <br>
        <p>Sample poses done with test charecter</p> <br>
        <img src="content/animation/Pose3.jpg" alt="Test poses for animation">

        <br>

        <img src="content/animation/Pose4.jpg" alt="More test poses for animation">

    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

**This is the page correctly displaying**

[image]

**What the menu looks like**

[image]

**Page with added pictures**

[image]

**Once I add the highlighted code, my title and a top video get cutoff, and I can't scroll upwards.**

[image]

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/Y4ySMCA Couldn't add images too my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace your css .content code with below code.

```
     .content {
        position: absolute;
        z-index: -1;
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
        color: #202020;
        height: auto;
      }
```

Comment: check this link https://fvvx7.csb.app/, 
dont forget to rate this answer as i am new at stackoverflow.
let me know if it doesnot fullfills your requirement.

Comment: Thank you so much this worked! Possible explanation as to why it works? Thanks again!!!

Comment: you were using transform, from -50%, due to negative value it will hiding half content section and then padding from top and left so i removed both